# OnCreate method keeps getting called repeatedly

Tags: android, oncreate

---

**Update:** Thank you all for attempting to help me solve this bug. I am still unsure as to the cause, I was able to roll back to a previous commit and continue development from there. This previous commit did show the same bug, however after I commented out  `button.performClick()` it went away. Strangely, this does not work on the most recent commit.

I still do not understand this bug and would appreciate any more assistance in helping determine the root cause. My greatest fear would be to inadvertently re-introduce it.

---

I have the most crazy error I have ever seen.

The OnCreate method is being called over and over again, freezing my application and giving me a slight flicker. The only solution is then to exit to the home screen and force quit the application from the settings menu.

Here is what is happening in detail:

1. Application starts (Main Activity)
2. Main Activity calls the Second Activity
3. Second Activity calls onCreate, sets up as normal
4. Second Activity randomly decides to exit onCreate <-- I think this what's happening
5. Second Activity's onCreate gets called again. It doesn't ever return to the Main Activity.

I have run a debugger, it appears that the second activity successfully completes the onComplete/onResume sequence, then decides to exit and restart.

Has anybody ever heard of this behavior before?

I haven't noticed any exceptions being thrown. Also, in the course of debugging, I did go ahead and check those locations that you see as silent fail. (this is the older code before I littered it with print statements)

**UPDATE:** When attempting to stop the process, I must turn on airplane mode. This means it has something to do with this code block  (Second Activity)

```
else if (Network.haveNetworkConnection(Login.getContext()) && Login.checkClientId())
        {...}
```

**With no internet, it will hit the else statement and does not display this behavior.**

**CODE:**

onResume() of the Main Activity, where I call the Second Activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //Check If logged in, else go to login page
        Login.setContext(getApplicationContext());

        //Reset Notification Number
        GCMIntentService.cancelNotifications();

        /** GO TO LOGIN **/
        if(!Login.isLoggedIn())
        {
            //If user is not logged in, open login page
            System.out.println("RESUMING MAIN AND STARTING LOGIN INTENT");
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivityLogin.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else
        {
            Login.setupStuffOnce();
            Event.pullEvents(); //Get New Events

            //Update ListView
            updateMainFeed();
        }


    }
```

This is the Second Activity:

```
public class ActivityLogin extends Activity
{

    private String postData;
    //private Context c;
    //final Timer timer = new Timer();

    //Facebook Stuff
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(Config.FBAPPID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    //Layout Stuff
    EditText username, password;
    Button loginButton, signupButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Open Database
        Login.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        Database.open(getApplicationContext());
    }

    /*
     * @Override public void onPause() { s }
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // shouldn't put here but oh well
        init();

        //If coming from ActivitySignup
        if(Transfer.username != null)
        {
            username.setText(Transfer.username);
            password.setText(Transfer.password);
            Transfer.password = null;
            Transfer.username = null;
            loginButton.performClick();
        }

    }

    public void init()
    {

        Login.getUserLoggedIn();
        if (Login.isLoggedIn())
        {
            //Do Any Additional Setup
            Login.setupStuffOnce();

            // If user is logged in, open main
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (Network.haveNetworkConnection(Login.getContext()) && Login.checkClientId())
        {
            // Else, Make User Login
            // Inflate Login and Present Website
            String clientid = Login.getClientId();
            System.out.println("clientid:" + clientid);
            //System.exit(0);
            postData =  "mobile=1&client_id="+Login.getClientId();



            // Inflate the view
            setContentView(R.layout.activitylogin3);

            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);



            //Inflate the Button
            loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);

            signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivitySignup.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View view) {

                     int res = Login.sendLogin(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

                     if(res == 202)
                     {
                         //Login Successful

                         //Check if facebooked.
                         if(Login.isFacebooked())
                         {
                             //Just go to main
                             Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
                             //Are these flags necessary?
                             //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                             startActivity(intent);
                         } else
                         {
                             //Go to facebook login page
                             //Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityFBLogin.class);
                             //startActivity(intent);

                             //Login via Facebook
                             doFacebook();
                         }

                     } else
                     {
                         System.out.println("Login Failed: "+res);
                         if(res == 405)
                         {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             password.setText("");
                         }
                         else
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Not entirely true in all cases i think

                     }



                      /*Login.getUserLoggedIn();
                        if(Login.isLoggedIn())
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Login Above", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }*/
                  }
                });



        } else
        {
            // Not Logged In and No Internet Access

            setContentView(R.layout.activitylogintext);

            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("No Internet Connection Detected\n requires internet to login");

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Login.getUserLoggedIn();
                        if(Network.haveNetworkConnection(Login.getContext()))
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityLogin.class);
                            //intent.setFlags();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Access Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                  }
                });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void doFacebook()
    {
         facebook.authorize(this, Config.facebookPermissions, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                     /*SharedPreferences.Editor editor = state.edit();
                     editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                     editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                     editor.commit();
                        */
                     //Input into database
                     Login.saveAccessToken(facebook.getAccessToken());
                     Login.setFB(facebook.getAccessToken());
                     //Login.sendAccessToken(facebook.getAccessToken());

                     //Intent into Main Activity
                     Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
                    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: "+error.getErrorType(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {}
            });
    }

    public boolean checkForUserID(Context c)
    {
        try{
            String res = Network.getUrl("www.website.com/mobile.php?got_user=1&client_id="+Login.getClientId());
            JSONObject json = JSON.constructObject(res);
            if(JSON.handleCode(json))
            {
                if(json.getString("type").equals("userid"))
                {
                    Login.setLogin(json.getString("data"));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Silent Fail
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you must post some code.At least of starting activity from Main Activity. And onCreate() of second activity

Comment: It won't randomly decide to exit; I know of only three things that can occur 1) Exception (should be in logcat) 2) normal return (e.g. `return` or run-off-end) or 3) process is killed (which should not happen).

Comment: That being said, I have also heard to issues caused by passing a *negative* value to `startActivityForResult` or calling `finish` in onCreate (this won't necessarily change any of the exit points, but may lead to other interactions)

Comment: I haven't noticed any exceptions. I will be posting code shortly

Comment: My code-blind vote is for -- you are invoking Second Activity from the Second Activity's `onCreate`

Comment: dude post some code ..................

Comment: I have posted code from both the main and second activities

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the problem will be resolved if you finish your `MainActivity` after you call `SecondActivity`. The problem probably is that the `onResume` event is immediatelly fired when you resume your `MainActivity`. That is because the `MainActivity` was probably destroyed and recreated while it was in background. Another solution would be to save your Activity's state with `onSaveInstanceState`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/1482726) for more information.

Comment: I will test this shortly. However I do not think it is returning to the MainActivity at all.

Comment: Unfortunately calling finish() in main did not solve the issue

Answer (score 4):

Check this code in your activity:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

                    if(Network.haveNetworkConnection(Login.getContext()))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityLogin.class);
                        //intent.setFlags();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Access Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
              }
            });
```

Here you are calling ActivityLogin itself.
That's why the `onCreate()` is being called again and again.

Comment: I'll recheck this section. However since this is in the onClick() method of a button, I do not feel that this is the issue.
The reason for this is that it restarts the activity in order to check   for a internet connection and update the screen if required.

Comment: @TheRealKingK, Ok. And check if(!Login.isLoggedIn()) case in first activity, too. It will also restart the ActivityLogin.

Comment: I'm checking the button. However, it does successfully complete both the onCreate and onResume methods. Which should rule out this problem since it is located in onCreate.

Comment: @TheRealKingK `loginButton.performClick();` - won't that fire `onClick`? (I think this explanation makes sense. Start commenting out code; e.g. the `performClick` until you find the cause.)

Comment: There is some failed case and hence recursive calls

Comment: @pst I will check that possibility. However they are two different variables. "loginButton" is class. "button" is local method.

Comment: ShreyaShah I have ruled out this possibility.
@pst I have ruled out performClick() as well.
I appreciate your help, this problem is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem once. The problem occurred because I made configuration changes without declaring them in the `android:configChanges` attribute of the `<activity>` tag (and hence it recreates itself the whole time).

For example, if you change the locale manually you need to add `locale` to `android:configChanges`!

Comment: I was really hoping that it was this. But after testing every single possible case I could catch, I'm forced to conclude it wasn't. But thanks for the information

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you change the locale? If yes, do you test on 4.2? If yes, you must add layoutDirection (that was the problem in my case) in addition to locale to the configChanges!

Comment: I could not add layoutDirection, probably because it was added in API 17. It did not seem to recognize that flag as valid. I am testing for API 8 (2.2).

Answer (score 2):

I think your main problem is with you onResume function as it gets called each time it comes back into view (eg: you start second activity, finish it, main activity onResume is called again. If you finish your second activity (or it quietly crashes for some reason) you will go back to your mainActivity and call onResume (which will start the cycle all over again).

Now i dont know if you are finishing activity 2 somehow but I would check that.

EDIT:
ALso I would put some logcats here

```
if (Login.isLoggedIn())
{
      //Do Any Additional Setup
      Login.setupStuffOnce();

      // If user is logged in, open main
      Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
      //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      Log.i("Some Tag", "Starting Main Activity From Activity 2");
      startActivity(intent);

}
```

The above adding of the log.i will allow you to know if this is where the error happens, and you can go from there.

Comment: As I previously mentioned, It never returns to the Main.onResume(). I have checked this behavior extensively.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there is a good chance for endless cycling here if `Login` is not properly shared between the activities, causing `Login.isLoggedIn()` to return `true` in `ActivityLogin` but `false` in `ActivityMain`.

A few critical factors are where your `Login` object is located, is it static, how is it referenced between Activities? It is entirely possible that ActivityMain is being destroyed while ActivityLogin is active; storing the Login data in `SharedPreferences` or a database, or otherwise persisting it is important. How does `isLoggedIn()` resolve (determine its `return` value?)

Suggestion 1: Consider making use of the Singleton pattern (if you haven't already.)
Suggestion 2: While discouraged, you could store `Login` at the `Application` level.
Suggestion 3: You can try using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to reduce the likelyhood of a new ActivityMain being created - which might not have access to `Login`, again depending on how you have it stored.

#### ActivityMain

```
onResume() {
    if(!Login.isLoggedIn()) {
        /* Not logged in, launch ActivityLogin! */
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivityLogin.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

#### ActivityLogin

```
onResume() { /* ... */ init(); }

init() {
    Login.getUserLoggedIn();
    if (Login.isLoggedIn()) {
        /* Internet - launch ActivityMain! */
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityMain.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // <--- suggested addition
        startActivity(intent);
    else if (Network.haveNetworkConnection(Login.getContext()) && Login.checkClientId()) {
        /* No internet, the user was unable to login. */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem where the activity would be recreated all the time. Re-installing the app wouldn't help, but **restarting the phone** did the job.

Comment: wow! I'm happy that people are still looking at my post! Unfortunately I did try restarting the phone to no luck.